# Target Images directly in jQuery Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I love the way this script works: http://demo.marcofolio.net/bgimg_slideshow/

However, I was wondering, **is there a way to to target each image in the slideshow directly?**

So, I could click a hyperlink that says 'Image 3' and it would load a certain image - rather than use the current navigation buttons.

This is the script itself: http://demo.marcofolio.net/bgimg_slideshow/js/script.js, but I just need to know how to target each image directly in my HTML.

Can anyone help me with this?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each image is not loaded in the slideshow concurrently - rather, there's a single element that displays each image, and the slideshow works by changing the source for the image.

However, you should be able to work around this if you just want to create a link to automatically load a certain image. The image data is stored in an array named "photos", so you should be able to create a button that triggers the loading of a given photo. The script uses a function "navigate" to go backwards and forwards, so what you'll need to do is modify it to allow arbitrary photos to be loaded.

Something like this

```
var navigate_to = function(image_number) {
  if(animating) {    
    return;    
  }  
  currentImg = image_number;

  var currentContainer = activeContainer;
  if(activeContainer == 1) {
    activeContainer = 2;
  } else {
    activeContainer = 1;
  }
  showImage(photos[currentImg - 1], currentContainer, activeContainer);
};
```

Should work, but I haven't tested it - you might need to massage the indexes a bit for it to work perfectly. Then, all you need to do is create a link that will call this function with the index it's pointing to.

To be more specific on this last point, you can create an element like this -

```
<div class="navigator">1</div>
```

Then add this code -

```
$(".navigator").on("click", function () {
  navigate_to(parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
});
```

There's no need to specifically create a hyperlink, since this is in-page navigation. What this will do is if an element with the class "navigator" is clicked, the value in the element will be sent to "navigate_to". So long as you put integers in the navigate elements, this should work well enough.

Comment: Thank you, Bubbles. Can you explain how I would use this with an HTML hyperlink?

Comment: I've expanded my answer, hopefully it's enough for you to get this to work for you.

Comment: Many, many thanks Bubbles. I will give this a try just now & will let you know how I get on :-D

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to like me :-D http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3NK/ Any ideas, what I'm doing wrong here? Clicking '1' does nothing :'(

Comment: A [fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu3NK/2/). I think you're going to have to take it from here, I can't fix every little issue unless you have a budget for an independent contractor for this ;)

Comment: Many thanks again, Bubbles. I now just need to figure out how to change the image when the link is clicked :)

Comment: The version I posted does change the image to the one on the beach; make sure you have a different image up when you click.

Comment: Yeap, I messed up. It now works beautifully. I'll tweak some bits later on - many, many thanks Bubbles - you're a star!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change image using showImage() function.

```
showImage(photoObject, currentContainer, activeContainer)
```

Comment: Hi roasted. Many thanks for the reply.
Can you possibly show me how this works with an example? I'm not so hot with JS. Would really appreciate it :)